# Knot-tying with polymorphic variants

Tags: ocaml

I have a variant defined in a module, and another module that basically extends the variant with a few more cases, so I'm using a polymorphic variant.

To prevent the subexpressions in `Extended.exp` being those of `Core.exp`, the knot is tied later.

```
module Core = struct
  type 'a expr_f = [
    | `Int of int
    | `Plus of 'a expr_f * 'a expr_f
  ]

  type expr = expr expr_f
end

module Ex = struct
  type 'a expr_f = [
    | 'a Core.expr_f
    | `Times of 'a expr_f * 'a expr_f
  ]

  type expr = expr expr_f
end
```

This seems to work, until we use a recursive function to traverse a value of type `Ex.expr`.

```
let rec test : Ex.expr -> Ex.expr = function
  | `Int i -> `Int i
  | `Plus (a, b) -> `Plus (test a, test b)
  | `Times (a, b) -> `Times (test a, test b)
```

I get a type error with this because the type of `Expr.expr_f` is:

```
type 'a expr_f = [
  | `Int of int
  | `Plus of 'a Core.expr_f * 'a Core.expr_f
  | `Times of 'a expr_f * 'a expr_f
]
```

The subexpressions are using `Core.expr_f`, which doesn't support the additional `Times` case.

What should I do to resolve this?

I'm not sure if I should just not declare the variant and have it left open because I do want to benefit from exhaustiveness checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to "tie the knot later", this is the definition you should have:

```
module Core = struct
  type 'a expr_f = [
    | `Int of int
    | `Plus of 'a * 'a
  ]

  type expr = expr expr_f
end

module Ex = struct
  type 'a expr_f = [
    | 'a Core.expr_f
    | `Times of 'a * 'a
  ]

  type expr = expr expr_f
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I found the same answer here as well. http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/papers/fose2000.html